# How to do an IN query in Solr?

Tags: syntax, solr

i'm having documents with a multivalued field "sharedTo" which contains the groups that the document is shared to. Now I want to find all documents that are shared to at least one of a list of given groups. E.g. I want to find all documents that are shared to the group "foo" or the group "bar" or both. Currently I'm building a query like this:

```
sharedTo:"foo" OR sharedTo:"bar"
```

For each group I just add a new OR query part. This works, however I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this like a

```
sharedTo IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

if your default operator is OR, then you can just give the query as

**sharedTo:('foo' 'bar')**

If your default operator is AND, then you'll have to do it like this: **sharedTo:(foo OR bar)**

Comment: Anyone know if there is a practical or hard limit to the number of terms here? (i.e. 'foo' 'bar')

Comment: @UpTheCreek Yes there is an upper limit to this, it's mostly based on the size of the URL that Solr will accept.  If the URL is too long it will return a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: You don't need the quotation marks around the terms btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **SolrJ** as client your query would look like as follows:

```
fq=sharedTo:("foo" OR "bar")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me. But this syntax did

column_name:+(value1 value2)

http://harmssite.com/2012/09/solr-query-for-mimicking-sql-in-operator-functionality/

Comment: Unfortunately that link is dead