# Foreach Loop slow with API search

Tags: php, solr, foreach

I have an array of IDs that I am doing foreach loop and searching each ID in a SOLR index using Php Apache SOLR client. Its slow like a dead turtle. Any help appreciated in optimizing this

```
    foreach ( $f_games as $game_id ){   
        $game_type = BKT_PLUGIN_CLASS::tv_regions($game_id);
        //Do my stuff
        $count++;
    }
```

Where

> BKT_PLUGIN_CLASS::tv_regions

is my class method for SOLR API search ( which works fine, no issues there ).

So its doing what i want it to do. It takes each ID and goes to SOLR and brings the result of that item and I do what I want to do and increase count. With only 200+ IDs, it takes more than 2 minutes to spit out results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) in Solr - that way you can get *x* number of hits for each region, all rolled up into a single response. Tweak the number of groups and number of hits for each group to match your need.

Filter the list by having a `fq` with all the values in, so that it returns the documents you need, then group by the value you'd normally search for.

Answer (score 0):

Why are You pinging API for each game? You are loosing lot of time just to connect there ...
Can't You just pass all IDs and just count result?
I don't know SOLR well but for me it's insane that it's not possible (so I assume that it is doable)
[How to do an IN query in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960602/how-to-do-an-in-query-in-solr)
[How can I search on a list of values using Solr/Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613592/how-can-i-search-on-a-list-of-values-using-solr-lucene)

Comment: I can't. It lets me search and get 10 results at a time even if I send all 200+ IDs at a time, I get 10 back.

Comment: @WaliHassan add `&rows=XXX` to your query where XXX is the maximum number of results you want.